# Temperature unit converter in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am starting to learn python and this has been my first project but I am not entirely happy, I think it could be done better. Could you help me? The strings are in Spanish but I think it does not harm understanding.

```
    elegir_magnitud = int(input(
"""1 = Temperatura
2 = Longitud 
3 = Masa
4 = Volumen
5 = Tiempo
6 = Divisa
Entra número deseado: """))
if elegir_magnitud == 1 :
    unidad_temperatura = int(input(
        """         

------------------Elige la unidad de temperatura a ser convertida:---------------
1 = Celsius
2 = Farhengei o como se escriba
3 = Kelvin
Entra número deseado: """))
    cantidad_temperatura = float(input(
        """

Entra la cántidad de esa unidad deseada: """))
#ELEGIR UNIDAD DE TEMPERATURA A CONVERTIR
    unidad_a_convertir = int(input(
        """         

--------------------Elige la unidad de temperatura a convertir:-----------------
1 = Celsius
2 = Farhengei o como se escriba
3 = Kelvin
Entra número deseado: """))
    if unidad_temperatura == unidad_a_convertir:
        print("Por qué quieres convertir a la misma unidad?")
    if unidad_temperatura == 1 and unidad_a_convertir == 3:
        print("""El resultado de la conversion es: \n""",float(cantidad_temperatura - 273),"ºK")
    if unidad_temperatura == 1 and unidad_a_convertir == 2:
        print("""El resultado de la conversion es: \n""",float(cantidad_temperatura * 9%5 +32),"ºF")
    if unidad_temperatura == 3 and unidad_a_convertir == 1:
        print("""El resultado de la conversion es: \n""",float(cantidad_temperatura + 273),"ºC")
    if unidad_temperatura == 3 and unidad_a_convertir == 2:
        print("""El resultado de la conversion es: \n""",float((cantidad_temperatura -273) * 9 % 5 + 32),"ºF")
    if unidad_temperatura == 2 and unidad_a_convertir == 3:
        print("""El resultado de la conversion es: \n""",float((cantidad_temperatura - 32) % 9 * 5 - 273),"ºK")
    if unidad_temperatura == 2 and unidad_a_convertir == 1:
        print("""El resultado de la conversion es: \n""",float(cantidad_temperatura % 9*5 -32),"ºC")
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Localisation

> The strings are in Spanish

Great! However, that's not the only thing in Spanish: your variables (`elegir_magnitud`, `unidad_temperatura`, etc.) are as well.

This is non-ideal for at least a couple of reasons:

- Python, being a language whose syntax is written in English, conflicts with your code that is then a mixture of English and Spanish. This is inconsistent.
- For better or worse, the de-facto language of software development is English. Particularly for international collaboration or online open-source development, it is important to use a language that is accessible to more people.

It's a wonderful thing to apply internationalization (i18n) to your strings, but it should be to your strings only, and not the code.

### Factor out common code

Consider refactoring your code to:

- Have only one method that asks for units, called twice (once for source unit and once for destination unit)
- Make a tuple of coefficient-offset pairs. These represent the linear function from the given unit to Kelvin and back. This will only need two unit conversion formulae, rather than (worst-case) 2^n with the current strategy.

### Bug?

Are you sure that this works?

```
cantidad_temperatura % 9*5 -32
```

I doubt that modulus is the right thing to do here. You should be using division `/`.

### Example code

Notes:

- This does a rough i18n, with some strings from Google Translate (so my apologies for the likely poor Spanish).
- Only English and Spanish are implemented but any other language can be added.
- This assumes that your operating system is set to the correct locale
- For these purposes, only the [ISO639-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) language without country code is considered
- Enums are used for stricter type assurance
- Type hints are used for better static analysis and documentation
- I have not bothered to add the complexity of input validation, so if input is invalid, there will be an exception thrown
- Note the use of `locale` methods rather than direct `int` and `float` construction and formatting

**strings.py**

```
from locale import getlocale, getdefaultlocale


# For testing only
# from locale import setlocale, LC_ALL
# setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES.UTF8')


def get_lang() -> str:
    lang, _ = getlocale()
    def_lang, _ = getdefaultlocale()
    return (lang or def_lang)[:2]


LANG = get_lang()

if LANG == 'en':
    DIMENSIONS = (
      'Temperature',
      'Length',
      'Mass',
      'Volume',
      'Time',
      'Currency',
    )
    TEMP_UNITS = (
      'Kelvin',
      'Celsius',
      'Fahrenheit',
    )
    ENTER_NUMBER = 'Enter the desired number: '
    CHOOSE_TEMP_SOURCE = 'Choose the source temperature unit to convert: '
    CHOOSE_TEMP_DEST = 'Choose the destination temperature unit to convert: '
    PROVIDE_TEMP = 'Provide the source temperature: '
    RESULT = 'The result of the conversion is:'

elif LANG == 'es':
    DIMENSIONS = (
      'Temperatura',
      'Longitud',
      'Masa',
      'Volumen',
      'Tiempo',
      'Divisa'
    )
    TEMP_UNITS = (
      'Kelvin',
      'Centígrada',
      'Fahrenheit'
    )
    ENTER_NUMBER = 'Entra número deseado: '
    CHOOSE_TEMP_SOURCE = 'Elija la unidad de temperatura fuente para convertir: '
    CHOOSE_TEMP_DEST = 'Elija la unidad de temperatura de destino para convertir: '
    PROVIDE_TEMP = 'Proporcionar la temperatura de la fuente: '
    RESULT = 'El resultado de la conversión es:'
```

**convert.py**

```
from enum import Enum
from locale import format_string, atof, atoi
from typing import TypeVar, Type, Iterable

from strings import *


class Dimension(Enum):
    TEMPERATURE = 1
    LONGITUDE = 2
    MASS = 3
    VOLUME = 4
    TIME = 5
    CURRENCY = 6


class TempUnit(Enum):
    KELVIN = 1
    CELSIUS = 2
    FAHRENHEIT = 3


# To get from this unit to Kelvin:
# kelvin = m * this_unit + b
TEMP_PARAMETERS = {
    # This unit       m  b
    TempUnit.KELVIN: (1, 0),
    TempUnit.CELSIUS: (1, 273.16),
    TempUnit.FAHRENHEIT: (5/9, 273.16 - 5/9*32),
}


InputEnum = TypeVar('InputEnum', bound=Enum)


def enum_from_input(t_enum: Type[InputEnum], labels: Iterable[str]) -> InputEnum:
    print(
        '\n'.join(
            format_string('%d = %s', (enum.value, label))
            for enum, label in zip(t_enum, labels)
        )
    )
    result = t_enum(atoi(input(ENTER_NUMBER)))
    print()
    return result


def main():
    dimension = enum_from_input(Dimension, DIMENSIONS)
    if dimension != Dimension.TEMPERATURE:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    print(CHOOSE_TEMP_SOURCE)
    source = enum_from_input(TempUnit, TEMP_UNITS)
    print(CHOOSE_TEMP_DEST)
    dest = enum_from_input(TempUnit, TEMP_UNITS)

    temp1 = atof(input(PROVIDE_TEMP))

    # Use a simple linear transformation where y = mx + b; first convert to
    # the base unit (Kelvin)
    m, b = TEMP_PARAMETERS[source]
    kelvin = m*temp1 + b

    # Now calculate inverse to the destination unit
    m, b = TEMP_PARAMETERS[dest]
    temp2 = (kelvin - b)/m

    print(format_string('%s %.1f', (RESULT, temp2)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Example output**

```
1 = Temperatura
2 = Longitud
3 = Masa
4 = Volumen
5 = Tiempo
6 = Divisa
Entra número deseado: 1

Elija la unidad de temperatura fuente para convertir: 
1 = Kelvin
2 = Centígrada
3 = Fahrenheit
Entra número deseado: 3

Elija la unidad de temperatura de destino para convertir: 
1 = Kelvin
2 = Centígrada
3 = Fahrenheit
Entra número deseado: 2

Proporcionar la temperatura de la fuente: 81
El resultado de la conversión es: 27,2
```

Comment: +1 for localisation.